# Detect drop coordinates on SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have an svg component which is a droppable surface , also i have an html "li" element which is draggable. How could i accurately detect the coordinates of the drop on the SVG element ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you use for drag? d3?

Comment: I use jquery. I am not aware if we could do a html drag using d3